# Custom find list in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp

I need a list of employees, but, the age information too (column), in the other words:

```
<option value="id" data-age="age">Name</option>
```

How can I do that in CakePHP? Only with a foreach? For example:

```
foreach ($employees as $emp) { ?>
    <option
        value="<?php echo $emp['Employee']['id'] ?>" 
        data-age="<?php echo $emp['Employee']['age'] ?>">
        <?php echo $emp['Employee']['name'] ?>
    </option>
<?php } ?>
```

And, how can I do that keeping the `name/id` generate by CakePHP?

Comment: Create your own helper that extends cakephp's form helper. Override the `select` method and add your own support. Or just `foreach` it like you posted.

Comment: Actually the form helper is capable of doing this already, at least in Cake 2.x, not sure about older Cake versions tough...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In case you are using Cake 2.x, then you can let the `FormHelper` do this for you, you just need to format the options data correctly, and by correctly I mean an array holding arrays with at least `name` and `value` keys for the `option` element text and the `id` attribute, all additional entries will be mapped as attributes where the key is used as the attribute name, and the value as as the attribute value.

https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.0.2/lib/Cake/View/Helper/FormHelper.php#L2325

Here's an untested example. The options data should look like this:

```
$options = array
(
    array
    (
        'name' => 'employee-a',
        'value' => 1,
        'data-age' => 20,
    ),
    array
    (
        'name' => 'employee-b',
        'value' => 2,
        'data-age' => 30,
    ),
    array
    (
        'name' => 'employee-c',
        'value' => 3,
        'data-age' => 40,
    ),
);
```

And then just pass it to the form helper that creates a `select` element:

```
echo $this->Form->input('employee_id', array('type' => 'select', 'options' => $options));
```

This should generate the following HTML:

```
<select id="ModelEmployeeId" name="data[Model][employee_id]">
    <option value="1" data-age="20">employee-a</option>
    <option value="2" data-age="30">employee-b</option>
    <option value="3" data-age="40">employee-c</option>
</select>
```